# Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, upgrade, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-mvc-5

I upgraded my MVC 4 app to MVC 5 a couple of days ago following these [instructions](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) and now I'm getting the following error. I updated DotNetOpenAuth to the latest bits using Nuget (v4.3.3.13295) but it still throws this error.

How do I fix this?

> Inheritance security rules violated by type:
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.OutgoingWebResponseActionResult'. Derived
>   types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or
>   be less accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this finally. Turned out that I needed to make some changes to the source code of *DotNetOpenAuth* and re-compile it. This wasn’t easy at all since the source code won’t compile after downloading from github. I had to spend ~3 days trying various things and learning the build system meshed into *DotNetOpenAuth*’s project files until I finally got it to compile. Seems the author of this project has abandoned it. See more about this issue [here](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/307).

1. Download the 4.3 code base using this command line: **git clone -b v4.3 https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.git**
2. Edit the **/src/version.txt** and change it to **4.4.0**. This makes this version higher than the official Nuget release so that installing Nuget packages don’t attempt to install old versions of *DotNetOpenAuth* assemblies from its repository.
3. Remove all instances of the following string from all *AssemblyInfo.cs* files under the **/src/** directory.

   *[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]*
4. I had to mess around with the *Microsoft.Contracts* reference in two projects and point it to **/tools/Contracts/PublicAssemblies/v3.5/Microsoft.Contracts.dll** and then use a using *alias* to get classes from this assembly to resolve properly. A few *Requires.NotNull()* lines refused to compile so I just commented them out… c'est la vie..
5. Run the following command to skip verification of these assemblies: `sn.exe -Vr *,2780ccd10d57b246`

Once the assemblies were built I referenced those, re-added *Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth* 3.0 from Nuget, rebuilt my solution, and finally my app is up and running on MVC 5.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this, saved me from tons of problems. I had to skip strong name verification using: sn.exe -Vr "*,2780ccd10d57b246"

Comment: I had to run this too unfortunately. Added it to my answer above. The strong naming key files are encrypted with a password so you can't re-compile and pass the output off as the real deal. Makes sense, but if the project is abandoned it would be nice if the author were to un-encrypt the keys so someone can pick up the torch.